# How to notify user through Launcher Icon overlay

Tags: android, notifications

### Hey all,

1). Best way to notify user when application is focused(Note: redirection is required means a button click) and even when application is not focused

2). Guidance for notifying user through making changes in Launcher Icon(Like happens in many iPhone Apps and Android Apps as well), overlay kind of thing, an incremented number or something..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

> Best way to notify user when application is focused

Update the UI of the activity.

> and even when application is not focused

Use a `Notification`.

> Guidance for notifying user through making changes in Launcher Icon

That is not possible on Android AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry i m still new in Android, so don't have anymore idea about updating UI but my requirement is to show a dialog box when app is opend and show some notification except Status Bar Notification and Toast.. so now tel me what are the options i have?

Comment: @Ankit: Tell whoever gave you the "requirement" that I think they need to learn how to work properly with a platform. Then, do not "show a dialog box when app is opend" and don't "show some notification except Status Bar Notification and Toast".

Comment: @CommonsWare: agreed as if google people also says, don't do which is not required in an android app, but i, at least have to try and show my seniors that these are the problems which may occur. By the way **Thanks a lot** for ur replies and please do tel me if you know how to pop up a dialog box within from a Service on any Activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i also don't whether we can get some event's on launcher icon, is there another way around, i mean by using widgets or some thing....... ???????/

Comment: @CommonsWare: isn't Overlaying a Launcher Icon possible through creating AppWidget within my application, and i wanna ask whether it can slow down my application if i create a widget for this.

Comment: @Ankit: An app widget is not an launcher icon, though you can certainly make one that looks like a launcher icon and can be dynamically updated (e.g., show unread messages). A properly-implemented app widget will have no performance impact on your application. However, the user has to add the app widget to their home screen -- you cannot force it upon them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks i had implemented that AppWidget and through that overlay on icon.